# Font family not applying in firefox

Tags: font-face

I wish to use font 'Bellota' in my website.I downloaded the font (formats-> .otf, .woff, .woff2, .eot) and copied to the folder named 'font' and I called this font in my stylesheet using the code:​

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bellota';
    src: url("fonts/Bellota-Regular.eot");
    src: url("fonts/Bellota-Regular.eot") format("embedded-opentype"), 
        url("fonts/Bellota-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"), 
        url("fonts/Bellota-Regular.woff") format("woff"), 
        url("fonts/Bellota-Regular.otf"); 
}
```

Now the font is displayed in chrome but not in Firefox. Should anything be done specifically to use it in firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Firefox does not support the EOT file type](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eot) thus making the whole @font-face destructed. Removed it and only put WOFF file in the CSS and it should work fine now.